# How to get all checkboxes values in angular material2 without using any kind of forms

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular-material2

I am building my checkboxes using `ngFor`:

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let cb of (myList$ | async)">
      <mat-checkbox
        [value]="cb.name"
        [checked]="cb.checked"
        (change)="checkboxChange($event)" // only giving single value
        >{{ cb.name }}</mat-checkbox
    </ng-container>
```

the `(change)="checkboxChange($event)"` giving only one single value but I am looking for all the checkboxes values.

Any ideas how to get all the checkboxes `checked` values without using any sort of forms?

Can not see anything like that in the docs https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/overview

Comment: have you checked :https://material.angular.io/components/list/overview#selection-lists ?

Comment: @CruelEngine thanks for pointing out to that, but my checkbox container view is not a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use any forms, then you will have to modify the same list which you are iterating to store the updated values.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let cb of list">
      <mat-checkbox
        [checked]="cb.checked"
        (change)="cb.checked = $event.checked;
        checkboxChange()" >{{ cb.name }}
      </mat-checkbox>
</ng-container>
```

comp ts file

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular';
  myList$;
  list = []

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myList$ = of([
      {
        name: 'A', checked: true
      },
      {
        name: 'B', checked: false
      },
      {
        name: 'C', checked: true
      }]);

    this.myList$.subscribe((data) => {
      this.list = data;
    })

  }

  checkboxChange() {
    console.log(this.list)
  }
}
```

See this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-checkbox-without-form?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Note : Also I am using a separate `list` to iterate which is not an observable because that will be helpful to get all the updated checkbox values.